# Why is TTFB so long for 304 response from MVC OutputCache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-7.5, outputcache

I have configured the main action for our home page with the OutputCache filter as follows:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 172800, Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, VaryByCustom = "browser")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Note that this action returns a page based on the type of browser being used.  I have a custom view engine that returns a different view depending on if the browser is desktop, tablet or mobile, hence the vary by browser.

On the production site this shows a roughly 300ms TTFB all the time.  Why does it take so long to return?

[image: DevTools Timings]

This is for a 304 response.

IIS 7.5 running MVC5

No database calls involved.

Surely this request should be served straight out of RAM?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How much data is it? I think a 304 response just means that the server is serving up a cached page instead of generating it, but that doesn't mean it doesn't still have to download. And also depends on what else is going on in the server. If it's a small amount of data and the server isn't doing anything else then I would say this is odd though.

Comment: I'm not working on that project any more but it was a simple HTML page ... about 70KB.